# How to use the 'MESH_OT_extrude_verts_indiv' parameter?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, extrude

I'm trying to extrude a single vertex several times in a loop for different directions. For that I'm using the function: `bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_vertices_move(MESH_OT_extrude_verts_indiv=???,TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(new_direction)})`

If I use this function without the `MESH_OT_extrude_verts_indiv` it will extrude the last active vertex, wich is the one I just extruded.
The problem is that I don't know what to put in `MESH_OT_extrude_verts_indiv`. I tried to put the vertex in that loop index, but I can't put a Vector type in it.

Can anyone give me an example of what to put in this `MESH_OT_extrude_verts_indiv`?

Here is my code:^

```
for k in range(0,5): 
    for v in bpy.context.active_object.data.vertices: 
        bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_vertices_move(MESH_OT_extrude_verts_indiv=v,TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(v.co+new_direction)})

#new_direction is a random vector
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use bmesh**

[image]

Strongly recommend using bmesh instead of `bpy.ops.mesh` whenever you can.

Here is my understanding of the script needed.  Extrudes the individual selected vertices randomly a number of repeats.

The operators return dictionary has the newly created vertices and edges.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
from random import uniform

context = bpy.context
ob = context.edit_object # edit mode!
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]
for repeats in range(5):
    ret = bmesh.ops.extrude_vert_indiv(bm,
            verts=verts)
    for v in ret["verts"]: 
        v.co += Vector([uniform(-1, 1) for a in "xyz"])
    verts = ret["verts"]

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

If the idea is to extrude from the same vert  repeat times, then remove the line

```
verts = ret["verts"}
```